# Sending a data to a Web server

Tags: database, frameworks, iphone

I have already finished my iphone app, but I would to add some monitoring to it on my Web site. What I want is get a location of the device (state, country) that using my app and then after I got the location I want to send it to a Web Server. Then in my site I will create a report of how many user's of my app.
 I haven't work on Web Development, can anyone suggest how would I do it. What kind of data am I going to send on the server? Where should I store those data, in database, what database is better to use? How will I send those data? What framework should I included?
 Sorry for many questions, I just want to learn and got some idea from you experts.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but have a 3rd (4th?) option - Google Analytics. Works well with the iPhone, can trach user location, Browser/device type, and the number of hits. Presented nicely in on a colour-coded map, where you can click on a country to view detailed region data.

Along with the above, it also tracks the time spent on a page, on your site, and where users come from/go to.

did I mention it was free? You just need a Google account. http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect this kind of data, you are probably better off using an in-app analytics solution like Pinch Media, especially if you aren't familiar with web development.

Be aware though that users generally feel like they are being spied on, even though you aren't collecting an personally identifiable data.

Comment: I wanted to add some reports on how many users to my web. Do you know some Library that I can use to send data to my web server?

Answer (score 0):

Another option for this is Flurry Analytics.  These guys have already figured out how to collect information from your App (with just a few calls you make) and have free analytical software on their website that lets you statistically analyze what's going on with your App.

Though you can certainly collect, store and report on this information yourself, for straight-forward analysis, using a canned solution like this is the easiest approach.

Remember you cannot collect actual Location data without informing the user that you are doing so - so any detailed location data will have to be collected with the user's knowledge.

-t

Comment: If I am going to collect the location of the user what kind of data should I pass to the web server. What is the better database to use to store these data

Answer (score 0):

You can use boos::asio library. (As far as I know it's possible to compile it for iphone)